# Getting ParseException when running Hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, parseexception

I'm trying to find the number of employees who are paid less than average wage.

I'm pretty new to hive and struggling a bit, could someone explain whats wrong with my statement and help me out please?

My statement -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM(SELECT wage, AVG(wage) AS avgWage FROM emp_wages) WHERE wage < avgWage;
```

The error -

`ParseException line 1:82 cannot recognize input near 'where' 'wage' '<' in subquery source`

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A syntax error. Derived table should be aliased.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT wage, AVG(wage) AS avgWage FROM emp_wages group by wage)  t --alias needed here
WHERE wage < avgWage;
```

Query wise, it needs a change.

```
select count(*)
from (SELECT wage, AVG(wage) over() AS avgWage 
      FROM emp_wages
     ) t
where wage < avgWage
```

Comment: Your 2nd HQL is right. But isn't your  1st HQL  need group by for aggregation

Comment: You’re right..edited it to be syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is AVG is an aggregation function. If you want to map one to many relations, you need to use a cross join function:

```
select 
  count(*), avg(v1.wage),
  sum(case when v.wage < v2.avgwage then 1 else 0 end) below_average
from 
emp_wages v cross join (select avg(wage) as avgwage from emp_wages) as v2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT wage, AVG(wage) AS avgWage FROM emp_wages group by wage)avg --group by needed
WHERE wage < avgWage;
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct query would be:

```
select count(*) where wage <(select avg(wage) from emp_wages);
```

You are getting a parsing error as wage and avgWage is in subquery.